# ERROR: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Hero[]'

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

app.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [HeroService]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  heroes : Hero[ ];
  selectedHero : Hero;
  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }
      getHeroes(): void {
     this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  };
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getHeroes();
  };
    onSelect(hero: Hero): void{
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  };
}
```

**hero.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import { Hero } from './hero'; 
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes'; 

@Injectable() 
export class HeroService { 

    getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> { 
        return Promise.resolve(HEROES); 
    } 
}
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Can you show `getHeroes` method in your service?

Comment: guess you are returning `Hero[]` which should be `Promise<Hero[]>` instead at `heroService.getHeroes()`.

Comment: hero.service.ts file   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
  }
}

Comment: you should edit your initial question with that code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `this.heroService.getHeroes()` method returns a resolved promise.

It should be

```
this.heroes = this.heroService.getHeroes();
```

Comment: or `this.heroService.getHeroes().then((heroes => this.heroes = heroes);` depending if `|async` is used in the view or not.

Answer (score 18):

I got the same error; after I googled a few answers, I found that your code is no different to me and actually no error. Just need to restart the ng serve and then it compiled successfully.
reference: [Angular2 Tutorial: Promise error (type not assignable) in Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44216533/angular2-tutorial-promise-error-type-not-assignable-in-service)

Comment: Same here, edited hero.service.ts and saved, then it worked.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer.  I recompiled with 'ng serve'  and it worked

Comment: any explanation as to why ng serve needs to be restart?

Answer (score 2):

**Instead of**:

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> { 
  return Promise.resolve(HEROES); 
}
```

**Try this**:

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
  resolve(HEROES);
 });
}
```

It is working