# Angular2 Tutorial: Promise error (type not assignable) in Service

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-promise

I'm following the tutorial "[Angular Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/)" at the Angular.io site. 
I've setup the project with Angular CLI (see environment versions at the end of this post).

I'm stuck at [point 5 (services)](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html) :
using the same files provided by the tutorial, I get the following error in line 9 of 'hero.service.ts':

```
Failed to compile.

/home/myuser/angular-tour-of-heroes/src/app/hero.service.ts (9,4): Type 'Hero[]' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Hero[]>'.
  Property 'then' is missing in type 'Hero[]'.
```

This is the code of the service (file 'hero.service.ts'):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';

@Injectable()

export class HeroService {
  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
  }
}
```

And this is a snippet of the component (app.component.ts) that acts when the service promise resolves:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  heroes: Hero[];
  selectedHero: Hero;

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }
}
```

I just saw [this other post about a similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202862/angular2-error-while-resolving-promise-type-promisehero-is-no-t-assignabl) in the tutorial, but the error depicted there complaints about property 'length' instead of 'then':

```
Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'Hero[]'. Property 'length' is missing in type 'Promise'.
```

As I said, I'm stuck here, I don't know if my environment could have something to do with the error. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04  (ARM Chromebook with crouton Chroot), `node v7.10.0`, `npm 4.6.1`, `angular 4.1.3`, `angular-cli 1.0.6` :

```
$ ng --version
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.0.6
node: 7.10.0
os: linux arm
@angular/common: 4.1.3
@angular/compiler: 4.1.3
@angular/core: 4.1.3
@angular/forms: 4.1.3
@angular/http: 4.1.3
@angular/platform-browser: 4.1.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.1.3
@angular/router: 4.1.3
@angular/cli: 1.0.6
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.3
```

Comment: Try to restart `ng serve`. I have had similar issues, which then were gone.

Comment: webpack: Compiled successfully after restart. Thanks!